# 406 error on Spring MVC integration test, while the service works fine in browser

Tags: spring, rest, jackson, integration-testing

I have a Spring 4 MVC web application. I am doing the Integration Test for my REST Services. The services are working fine from invoking through browser rest-clients and jquery/restangular UI as well. However, when I run my Integration Test, I am getting the error `Expected :200   Actual :406`.

This issue comes only when Spring convert the Object to json. I tried manual conversion by ObjectMapper and returned the result. In this case, the test started working. 
Here are my files:

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/permissions", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getPermissions() throws Exception {
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(getPermissions(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Integration Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath*:rest-config.xml", "classpath:domain-config.xml"})
public class ITController {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.context).build();
    }
@Test
    public void getPermissions() throws Exception {
        MvcResult result = this.mockMvc.perform(get("/permissions/4")
                .accept("application/json"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json")).andReturn();
        Permission p = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(result.getResponse().getContentAsString(), Permission.class);
        Assert.assertNotNull(p);
    }
}
```

If I add the below code to the controller, then the test start working.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String stringVal = mapper.writeValueAsString(permission);
```

Part of my spring config file:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="order" value="1"/>
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
                    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json"/>
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
                    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="text/plain;charset=UTF-8"/>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I am using `jackson version 2.2.1` in my application.

**DEBUG Log**

```
2014-07-14 14:41:37 DEBUG EntityPrinter:121 - com.myapp.entity.Permission{isActive=true, description=permission, id=4, Name=mypermission}
2014-07-14 14:41:37 DEBUG JdbcTransaction:113 - committed JDBC Connection
2014-07-14 14:41:37 DEBUG JdbcTransaction:126 - re-enabling autocommit
2014-07-14 14:41:37 DEBUG LogicalConnectionImpl:314 - Releasing JDBC connection
2014-07-14 14:41:37 DEBUG LogicalConnectionImpl:332 - Released JDBC connection
2014-07-14 14:41:37 DEBUG ConnectionProxyHandler:219 - HHH000163: Logical connection releasing its physical connection
```

Comment: What are the logs telling you at DEBUG level?

Comment: Nothing related to error. It is printing the Permission Entity. Editing the post to add the relevant log